# SQL Query for retrieving data by combining two queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am writing two queries in my sql procedure to retrieve data based on the parameter provided from the user in my asp.net application.

```
IF @Action = 'ID'
  SELECT Name,FirstName,LastName,Employee_ID,Location FROM Salary WHERE  Employee_ID=@Employee_ID
ELSE IF @Action = 'LASTNAME'
  SELECT Name,FirstName,LastName,Employee_ID,Location FROM Salary WHERE LastName  like '%' + @LastName + '%'
```

Now what I want is to combine the query into single query so that irrespective of whether ID is passed as parameter or lastname is passed i must be able to get the data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Same functionality but a single where clause?

Comment: warning - `like '%' + @LastName + '%'` is going to give bad performance.  `CONTAINS` is better.

Comment: @Hogan can you provide me a reference link to learn about it.

Comment: @Sravan - I don't have a reference, just experience.  But it makes sense if you think about it, an index can't be used to match a starting wild card.  This is also true of Contains, but the engine can make use of internal string matching to gain performance.  Best option on sql-server is to use full text search.  (This essentially will make additional tables containing indexes of all of the words.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem

```
SELECT Name, FirstName, LastName, Employee_ID, Location FROM Salary
WHERE Employee_ID = ISNULL(@Employee_ID, Employee_ID) and LastName  LIKE '%' + 
ISNULL(@LastName,LastName) + '%'
```

Comment: ... so if nothing is passed to the variables, you'll get all the rows ? is this what you are asking ?

Comment: @armen that would be one scenario but ill be getting either of those values from my .net application...

Answer (score 2):

If all parameters can be used together:

```
SELECT Name,FirstName,LastName,Employee_ID,Location FROM Salary 
WHERE Employee_ID=@Employee_ID or LastName  like '%' + @LastName + '%';
```

One parameter - one call:

```
SELECT Name,FirstName,LastName,Employee_ID,Location FROM Salary 
WHERE (@Employee_ID is not null and Employee_ID=@Employee_ID)
   or (@Employee_ID is null and LastName  like '%' + @LastName + '%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
SELECT 
      Name
    , FirstName
    , LastName
    , Employee_ID
    , Location 
FROM dbo.Salary 
WHERE Employee_ID = ISNULL(@Employee_ID, Employee_ID)
    OR LastName  LIKE '%' + @LastName + '%'
```

Comment: i think the query needs to be changed.. i am getting all the data even when i specify only last name

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name,FirstName,LastName,Employee_ID,Location 
FROM Salary 
WHERE  (@Action = 'ID'       AND Employee_ID  = @Employee_ID)
OR     (@Action = 'LASTNAME' AND LastName  like '%' + @LastName + '%')
```

Comment: I dont want to have two values for action parameter. Need to get the job done by using single @Action parameter.

Comment: @Sravan: This sample uses a single variable, Action to filter based on the value of the variable, so it seems to satisfy the original requirements.

Comment: @PlantationGator: I dont find much difference between what i have written and what is over here. My intention of asking the question is to get rid of Action parameter. vemcaster and devart answers solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: @Sravan Oh I see, I didn't understand that was your intention from your original post.

Comment: @Pirion It turns out that there is a performance hit associated with using CASE as opposed to boolean logic, so there is in fact a reason to prefer the approach that you posted here as opposed to the one that I had posted. http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2003/11/14/513.aspx